# Nifi - Jetty Server directory listing

Tags: servlets, apache-nifi, embedded-jetty

Nifi, by default, allowed directory listing of its contents/docs. This is 'dirAllowed' property in jetty server. Is there any configuration which which i can set so that directory listing is disabled.

Nifi - 1.9.2

Example:
http://localhost:9088/nifi-docs/components/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was identified in [NIFI-6392](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6392) and addressed in version 1.10.0.

There is no configuration option in 1.9.2 which will allow you to disable the directory listing.